# Local isometry implies covering map for manifolds with boundary

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, complete-spaces

The following theorem is well known in the literature:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be riemannian manifolds and let $f : M \to N$ be a local isometry. If $M$ is complete and $N$ is connected, then $f$ is a covering map.

My question is: does the same theorem hold when we assume that $M$ and $N$ are now riemannian manifolds with boundary?

Comment: What do you mean by a local isometry in the case of manifolds with boundary? There are (at least two) genuinely different definitions.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer?

Answer (score 0):

One needs to define a notion of local isometry for manifolds with boundary in such a way that it becomes a local diffeomorphism between the manifolds. Then the thing to check is that map $f: M\to N$ satisfies the path-lifting property (which is a necessary and sufficient condition for a local homeomorphism to be a covering map). The proof of a path-lifting property is essentially the same as for manifolds without boundary: Take a rectifiable map $p: [0,1]\to N$ which admits a lift $\tilde{p}: [0,1)\to M$ and extend it continuously to $[0,1]$ using the fact that for each sequence $t_i\to 1-$, the sequence $(p(t_i))$ and, hence $(\tilde{p}(t_i))$ is Cauchy.